# Cakephp 3 Custom Pagination

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

Working in CakePHP 3.9.
I doing a page having multiple joins in a single query making it a complex query.
I wanted to have pagination for that page.
I tried using paginate and paginateCount function in a model which was working fine till CakePHP 2x.
But it is giving only the main table results and not including the joins.
Anyone who have succeeded facing this issue please help me.

My query below

```sql
SELECT
    Table1.*, Table2.*, Table3.*, Table4.* 
FROM
    (
        SELECT some columns 
        FROM some table 
        WHERE mulitple conditions 
    )
    as Table1 
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT some columns 
        FROM some table 
        join another table 
        WHERE mulitple conditions
    )
    as Table2 
    ON Table1.column1 = Table2.column1 
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT some columns 
        FROM some table 
        join another table 
        WHERE multiple conditions
    )
    as Table3 
    ON Table1.column1 = Table3.column1 
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT some columns 
        FROM some table 
        join another table 
        WHERE multiple conditions
    )
    as Table4 
    ON Table1.column1 = Table4.column1
```

It was simple doing custom query pagination in CakePHP2.x using paginate and paginateCount function but I am not able to do the same in CakePHP3.x

Is there any reference of doing this CakePHP3.x.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't show us your code, we can only guess.

Comment: I have updated my query. I am not able to make a paginate a page having above custom query.

Comment: Are you able to translate your query into Cake 3 ORM calls and just missing how to get that to work with pagination? Or you don't know how to do this query in the ORM?

Comment: I am not able to do this query in ORM. Hence I preferred to do custom query pagination. If you can help me in building the query or give reference. Thanks